# Auto-property vs property with a field

Tags: c#, oop, properties, field

Is there any difference between these two?

```cs
int a;
public int A
{
    get => a;
    set => a = value;
}
```

```
public int A { get; set; }
```

Comment: One is compiler generated and the other is not. Other than that no. If you were to put logic in getter and setter then yes they would be because you can't put getter and setter logic in an auto property.

Comment: Encapsulation!!

Comment: Sorry but what with encapsulation?

Comment: Now, why should you use an auto-property as opposed to a public field, when the auto-property does not have custom logic? Because you can *later*, when your requirements change, change the auto-property to a "manual" property *without breaking backwards compatibility*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public int A { get; set; }
```

is the exact same as saying:

```cs
private int _a;
public int A
{
    get => _a;
    set => _a = value;
}
```

[Auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) are simply syntactic sugar for a *private* field, and public getters and setters. It allows you to access and mutate a field (as a property) without the boilerplate of getter and setter methods. We must always encapsulate our data, and properties aim to speed up the process of writing that out

If this was java, you would have something like:

```java
private int a;

public void setA(int a){
    this.a = a;
}

public int getA(){
    return a;
}
```

When creating classes in java, you have to by force of habit define your getters, setters, hash code, and to string methods. Of course, modern IDE's will literally generate the stock implementations of these for you, but mentally it becomes a given. If there is no special logic in any of these methods that we routinely create, why be forced to write it out? Auto-props aim to take away a bit of the hassle. It just a quality-of-life bit of syntax for cleaner looking code. It tells you upfront that you have the stock accessors and mutators out of the box

Its also quite modular, take a look at the documentation to see how you can make for things like private setters, use `init` for immutability post-obj construction, etc

Its almost always preferable to use public properties over public fields in C#, easiest way to remember is: private fields, properties for any access mod above that

Comment: Can auto-properties have logic in getters and setters using the value keyword?

Comment: @Kovelj789 in that case you should use the "full property" notation `{ get => ...; set => ...; }`. Auto-prop syntax is meant to be very quick to write and "bare bones," and its sufficient for most cases

Comment: Auto-properties are also there to incentive devs to use public properties over public fields. Here is a great article on [field vs prop's effect on compatibility](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/PropertiesMatter) that discusses why to almost always prefer public properties